# How to print out app.debugDescription in Objective C for XCUIAppliaction

Tags: objective-c, nslog, xcode-ui-testing

I've seen some examples in Swift that describe how to print out the app.debugDescription in order to see the Accessibility hierarchy using the following:

```
print(app.debugDescription)
```

How would I go about doing this in Objective C?

I have this so far..

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
NSLOG(app.debugDescription);
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2347/_index.html

Comment: What's the output of your current Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [app debugDescription]);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%@", app.debugDescription);
```

Put the statements in the test setup, like so, and the tree will print in Xcode's console:

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    self.continueAfterFailure = NO;

    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];

    [app launch];

    NSLog(@"*** App Debug Description:\n%@", [app debugDescription]);
}
```